# Regular expression that stops at first letter encountered

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I want my regex expression to stop matching numbers of length between 2 and 10 after it encounters a letter.

So far I've come up with `(\d{2,10})(?![a-zA-Z])` this. But it continues to match even after letters are encountered.
`2216101225 /ROC/PL FCT  DIN 24.03.2022 PL ERBICIDE'` - this is the text I've been testing the regex on, but it matches 24 03 and 2022 also.
This is tested and intended for C#.

Can you help ? Thanks

Comment: Try `(?<=^\P{L}*)(?<!\d)\d{2,10}(?!\d)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/I7KrAL/2).

Comment: If you think about the problem slightly differently, are you actually interested in just matching numbers which appear at the start of the string (perhaps after some whitespace, etc)? If you can anchor to the start, you don't need the lookarounds

Comment: If you expect multiple numbers before any alphas, try [`\G[^\da-zA-Z]*(\d{2,10})`](https://regex101.com/r/zfov7a/1)

Comment: @bobblebubble Nice one, maybe if you also want to skip single digits `\G[^\da-zA-Z]*(?>\d[^\da-zA-Z]+)*(\d{2,10})` https://regex101.com/r/c6oBPl/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following .NET regex

```
(?<=^\P{L}*)(?<!\d)\d{2,10}(?!\d)
(?<=^[^a-zA-Z]*)(?<!\d)\d{2,10}(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I7KrAL/2). *Details*:

- `(?<=^\P{L}*)` - there must be no letters from the current position till the start of string (`(?<=^[^a-zA-Z]*)` only supports ASCII letters)
- `(?<!\d)` - no digit immediately on the left is allowed.
- `\d{2,10}` - two to ten digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit immediately on the right is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to anchor the pattern and to match any character except chars a-zA-Z or a newline, and then capture the 2-10 digits in a capture group.

Then get the capture group 1 value from the match.

```
^[^A-Za-z\r\n]*\b([0-9]{2,10})\b
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[^A-Za-z\r\n]*` Optionally match chars other than a-zA-Z or a newline
- `\b([0-9]{2,10})\b` Capture 2-10 digits between word boundaries in group 1

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mxq41P/1).

---

Note that in .NET `\d` matches all numbers except for only 0-9.